# odbc datasource connection at runtime through delphi

Tags: delphi, odbc, delphi-5

can we create ODBC datasource connection at runtime? If yes then can you plz help regarding how to do it. 
Currently I am created the ODBC datasource connection manually through Control Panel--> Administrative Tools --> Datasources. 
But i want to create that at runtime when user run application.

thanks for the help.

Comment: what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Wow. That software was released in the previous millenium. That's OLD. :-)

Comment: :( ya i know but dont have any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQLConfigDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716476%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([Delphi example](http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/creating-an-odbc-link-186049.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. As @TOndrej points out, you can create a ODBC datasource at runtime. But usually you don't need to. You might just create a Data Connection in runtime without an ODBC datasource.

Something like this, using ADO components to a MS Jet OLE DB ...

```
  if ADOConnection1.connected then ADOConnection1.close;
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
                'Data Source='+filename+';'+
                'Persist Security Info=False';
  ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:=false;
  ADOQuery1.Connection:=ADOConnection1;
  ADOConnection1.Open;
  ....
```

Comment: thats fine.. but i am using BDE components and i cant use another component. I have to stick with BDE.

Comment: No, you don't. :-)  You can change your components. BDE is dead, time to let it go.

Comment: I am using delphi professional 5 and its having BDE option only.

Comment: You could update to at least Delphi 2007, without doing a unicode port.  Or you could drop BDE and use a third party db option other than BDE, even in Delphi 5.  Delphi 5? Seriously? In 2011?

Comment: i have to use BDE only. . I dont have any other option. And i want to create data source at runtime.

Comment: I know, sometimes you also have to code with one of your hands at your back all the time.